# SVN branching base code into a project that updates

Tags: svn, repository, branch

firstly I do apologise if there are any duplicate questions. I did try (a little) to find it but with no success.

**The scenario:**

Say you have written your own PHP framework (as you do), and as it stands it's a shell with no scope (as it should be). Then you have a project that simply adds a few files here and there to make your magic happen, right?

I have repository A (the framework) that contains all my wheel-reinventing revolutionary source code. I want repository B (the project) that should contain the framework in its entirety (perhaps a branch of Repo A) as well as the few project files that make the magic happen. I want Repo B to update with any revisions made to Repo A but any changes to the project be restricted to Repo B (so not committing to A)

**My initial idea:**

Using a branch to create a copy of the framework, and then add my project files with no intention to ever merge. The problem with this is that the branch wont update any changes made after the copy, as SVN plans to merge changes later. I have also tried keeping the framework in one folder (checkout repo A), and the project-specific code in another folder (checkout repo B), but this is not a great solution as it means i can't use 1 gargantuous folder.

**My actual question:**

Is there a way I can either get a repository to extend (update only) another repository, or branch in such a way that the branched copy (the project) will keep track of revisions after it was copied.

**To be clear:**

1. I do not want separate repos in sub-folders e.g Symfony
   using src/A and src/B and vendor/C etc.
2. I am aware of conflicts, as projects may overwrite framework files here and there. It would boil down to due diligence when resolving any changes
3. To "just use git" is not an answer. I have SVN servers that took weeks to setup and changing that is going to be a nightmare, so not an option.

**My setup:**
I am using both Tortoise on windows and svn for linux in my local dev network. The repo servers are remote and run SVN 1.5.2 on CentOS 6 (if you ask me why 1.5.2, you better put aside 3 hours)

I am really hoping that I am missing something in the SVN world. I have only ever branched a couple of times, so hopefully I just don't know what I am doing and someone can just say "Here, dumb ass". Any feedback much appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of your generic code as if it was 3rd party code, then what you're describing sounds like the Subversion [Vendor Branch strategy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html) (with isn't actually SVN-specific)

From the SVN documentation:

> The solution to this problem is to use vendor branches. A vendor branch is a directory tree in your own version control system that contains information provided by a third-party entity, or vendor. Each version of the vendor's data that you decide to absorb into your project is called a vendor drop.
>
> Vendor branches provide two benefits. First, by storing the currently supported vendor drop in your own version control system, you ensure that the members of your project never need to question whether they have the right version of the vendor's data. They simply receive that correct version as part of their regular working copy updates. Second, because the data lives in your own Subversion repository, you can store your custom changes to it in-place—you have no more need of an automated (or worse, manual) method for swapping in your customizations.

However, you might also consider managing your generic code as if it were a 3rd party library or package.  Doing so would allow you to use other package management tools--not just the source control system.  For example, consider [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the material Jared, I have seen this before but when I saw my branch did not receive updates, I doubted branching altogether, will give it a read, looks promising, so here's a premature accept on your answer :)